# What is the meaning of this notation for a function?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, notation, contour-integration, piecewise-continuity

> A contour or path is a continuous mapping $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ which is piecewise continuously differentiable, i.e., there exist $a=a_0<a_1<...<a_n=b$ such that $\gamma_{|[a_{j-1},a_j]}$ is continuously differentiable for each $j$

What is the meaning of "$\gamma_{|[a_{j-1},a_j]}$" in this text?

Comment: It means $\gamma$ restricted to the interval $[a_{j - 1}, a_j]$.

Comment: What is the difference between that and $\gamma : [a_{j-1},a_j] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: "$\gamma:[a_{j-1},a_j] \rightarrow \Bbb{C}$" is a function whose domain is only $[a_{j-1},a_j]$ -- it is not the same as a function (defined on a larger domain) that is only being evaluated on that closed interval.

Comment: So in this context would it be wrong to write $\gamma : [a_{j-1},a_j] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ when referring to the function restricted in the interval $[a_{j-1},a_j]$?

Comment: Well, the whole point of the notation is that it is not true that $\gamma:[a_{j-1},a_j]\to \mathbb C,$ because $\gamma$’s domain is $[0,1].$ We do sometimes get sloppy with the notation, but better to be careful at first.

Comment: But another way of putting is that $\gamma’$ exists and is continuous on every interval $(a_{j-1},a_j).$ And it has a right derivative at each $a_{j-1}$ and a left-derivative at $a_j,$ with some continuity conditions. It gets complicated to say it correctly, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, if $f:X\to Y$ and $A\subseteq X,$ then $f_{|A}:A\to Y$ is the “restriction of $f$ to $A.$”

Technically, we first define $i_{A}:A\to X$ as the natural inclusion function, then define $$f_{|A}=f\circ i_A.$$

---

Functions have a fixed domain, so the function $f$ has only one domain.

Functions also have only one co-domain (slightly different from the “range” of a function.) Thus is sometimes a little odd.

For example: $f(x)=x^2$ can be defined as a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R,$ or we could define it as a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^{\geq 0}.$

Mathematicians play a little more fast and loose with the co-domains than they do with the domain, even though they are technically, trickier. Given a $B\subseteq Y,$ there isn’t always a corresponding function $f^{|B}:X\to B.$ (And that notation $f^{|B}$ is not, as far as I know, used at all, I just made it up for the sake of example.)

Comment: Actually, it is not really true that functions only have one codomain. Any superset of the range of $f$ is a codomain of $f$, and $f$ still satisfies the definition of a function without changing its elements, as such. Functions only do have one range, though, and every function is a surjection from its domain onto its range. The range is the image of the domain under $f$.